# How connect Fargate with Media convert?

Tags: aws-fargate, aws-media-convert

How connect the application layer (with containers on Fargate) in private subnet with AWS Media Convert? There is no VPC Endpoint for Media Convert.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no VPC support with MediaConvert at this time. (10/19/2020)